# HTML email table widths

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

UPDATED (WORKING) CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=600" />
            <title>Talent Academy Newsletter</title>
        </head>
    </html>

    <body width="700" style="width: 100% !important; background-color: #FFF; left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
        <!--[if mso]>
                        <center>
                        <table><tr><td width="700">
                        <![endif]-->
            <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top" height="auto" style="max-width: 700px!important left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;"> <!-- // wrapping table // --> 
            <tr>
                <td width="700" align="center" valign="top"> 
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr> 
                            <td align="center" valign="middle" width="700" style="background-color: #e7e7e7; height: 25; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica; color: #000;">
                                <p>Is Outlook ruining this pretty email? Click <strong>here</strong></p>  <!--**add link here when on FTP** e.g... <a href="http://www.feverpr.com/client/update/index.html" target="_blank" style="color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;"> --> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td align="center" valign="top" width="700" style="display: block; padding: 0;"> <!-- // welcome banner here // --> 
                                <img src="images/welcome.png" alt="Welcome!" height="340" width="700"> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="470" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;"> <!-- // into copy here // --> <!--be wary of width size here: 470--> 
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" width="470" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: League Gothic, Arial; color: #000; padding-top: 15px;">
                                <p>1st edition <br> September 2016</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" width="470" style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000; padding: 0px, 115px, 0px, 115px;"> <!--used another td as dif font/size --> 
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pharetra justo sed turpis rutrum, non molestie velit vehicula. Suspendisse sed est nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec sem odio, viverra eu velit vitae, posuere blandit orci. Integer placerat tempus tortor in pretium. Donec vitae magna et tortor maximus pulvinar vitae et magna. Nam aliquam molestie commodo.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr width="100%">
                            <td width="700" align="center" valign="top" width="700" style="display: block; padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom:50px;">
                                <img src="images/fever.png" alt="Welcome!" height="79" width="79">
                                <img src="images/nb.png" alt="Welcome!" height="79" width="79">
                                <img src="images/nbg.png" alt="Welcome!" height="79" width="79">
                                <img src="images/mw.png" alt="Welcome!" height="79" width="79">
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="700" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px 30px 0px;">
                                <img src="images/internal.png" alt="Internal Training" height="85" width="700">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="260" valign="top" align="center" style="max-width:260px!important; padding: 40px 63.5px 30px 20px;"> <!-- // bottom two //--> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>NAME:</strong> Training course 1 <br><strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi. <br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p>  
                                <img src="images/mw2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                                <img src="images/fever2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                            </td>
                            <td width="3" style="padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                                <img src="images/line1.png" alt="" height="200" width="3"> 
                            </td>
                            <td width="260" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 40px 20px 30px 63.5px;"> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>NAME:</strong> Training course 1 <br><strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi. <br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p> 
                                <img src="images/mw2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                                <img src="images/nbg2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="260" valign="top" align="center" style="max-width:260px!important; padding: 40px 63.5px 30px 20px;"> <!-- // bottom two //--> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>NAME:</strong> Training course 1 <br><strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi. <br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p>  
                                <img src="images/mw2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                                <img src="images/fever2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                            </td>
                            <td width="3" style="padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                                <img src="images/line1.png" alt="" height="200" width="3"> 
                            </td>
                            <td width="260" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 40px 20px 30px 63.5px;"> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>NAME:</strong> Training course 1 <br><strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi. <br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p> 
                                <img src="images/mw2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                                <img src="images/nbg2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;"> <!-- // start of external training section // --> 
                        <tr width="700">
                            <td width="700" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px 30px 0px;">
                                <img src="images/external.png" alt="Internal Training" height="85" width="700"> <!-- // banner image // --> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="260" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 20px 63.5px 20px 20px;"> <!-- // bottom two //--> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>NAME:</strong> Training course 1 <br><strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi. <br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p>  
                            </td>
                            <td width="3" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
                                <img src="images/line1.png" alt="" height="200" width="3"> 
                            </td>
                            <td width="260" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 63.5px;"> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>NAME:</strong> Training course 1 <br><strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi. <br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="700" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px 30px 0px;">
                                <img src="images/dare.png" alt="Dare to Share" height="85" width="700"> <!-- // banner image - dare to share section starts here // --> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="380" style="padding: 5px 0px 40px 20px;"> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>PELLENTESQUE HABITANT TRISTIQUE</strong><br>Nam at auctor ante. Integer finibus nisl at euismod iaculis. Proin eleifend nunc ante, hendrerit semper felis pellentesque non. Etiam id quam metus. Ut pretium congue turpis ullamcorper tempus. Vivamus finibus elit ipsum, sit amet egestas dolor condimentum nec.<br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p> 
                                <img src="images/icon_mail.png" alt="" height="26" width="33" align="left">
                                <img src="images/icon_web.png" alt="" height="31" width="31" align="left">
                            </td>
                            <td width="300" align="left">
                                <img src="images/circle_right.png" alt="Dare to Share" height="255" width="240" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 60px;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr>
                        <td width="300" align="left">
                                <img src="images/circle_left.png" alt="Dare to Share" height="255" width="240" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
                            </td>
                            <td width="380" style="padding: 5px 20px 40px 0px;"> 
                                <p align="right" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>PELLENTESQUE HABITANT TRISTIQUE</strong><br>Nam at auctor ante. Integer finibus nisl at euismod iaculis. Proin eleifend nunc ante, hendrerit semper felis pellentesque non. Etiam id quam metus. Ut pretium congue turpis ullamcorper tempus. Vivamus finibus elit ipsum, sit amet egestas dolor condimentum nec.<br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p> 
                                <img src="images/icon_mail.png" alt="" height="26" width="33" align="right">
                                <img src="images/icon_web.png" alt="" height="31" width="31" align="right">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="700" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px 30px 0px;">
                                <img src="images/firsthand.png" alt="Internal Training" height="85" width="700"> <!-- // banner image // --> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="380" style="padding: 5px 0px 40px 20px;"> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>PELLENTESQUE HABITANT TRISTIQUE</strong><br>Nam at auctor ante. Integer finibus nisl at euismod iaculis. Proin eleifend nunc ante, hendrerit semper felis pellentesque non. Etiam id quam metus. Ut pretium congue turpis ullamcorper tempus. Vivamus finibus elit ipsum, sit amet egestas dolor condimentum nec.<br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p>
                            </td>
                            <td width="300" align="left">
                                <img src="images/circle_right.png" alt="Dare to Share" height="255" width="240" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 60px;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="700" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px 30px 0px;">
                                <img src="images/useful.png" alt="Internal Training" height="85" width="700"> <!-- // banner image useful stuff // --> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="380" valign="top" align="center" style="max-width:400px!important; padding: 10px 30px 30px 20px;"> <!-- // bottom two //--> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>TIP OF THE MONTH</strong><br>Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi.</p>  
                                <img src="images/icon_speech.png" alt="" height="48" width="55" align="right" style="padding: 20px 20px 30px 0px;">
                            </td>
                            <td width="3" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                                <img src="images/line1.png" alt="" height="150" width="3"> 
                            </td>
                            <td width="217" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 10px 20px 30px 30px;"> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>USEFUL LINKS</strong><br>euismod.com<br>placerat.com<br>nullam.co.uk<br>efficitur.com</p> 
                                <img src="images/icon_comp.png" alt="NB" height="48" width="50" align="right" style="padding: 20px 20px, 30px 0px;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">
                        <tr width="100%">
                            <td width="700" align="center" valign="top" width="700" style="display: block;">
                                <img src="images/icon_facebook.png" alt="" height="24" width="15" style="padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;">
                                <img src="images/icon_insta.png" alt="" height="24" width="26" style="padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;">
                                <img src="images/icon_twitter.jpg" alt="" height="24" width="30" style="padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;">
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="470" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;"> 
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" width="470" >
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; padding: 0px, 115px, 0px, 115px;"><a href="mailto:charlotte.naish@nelsonbostockunlimited.com?Subject=Talent%20Academy" style="color: #000!important;  text-decoration: none;"><strong>charlotte.naish@nelsonbostockunlimited.com</strong></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <!--[if mso]>
                        <center>
                        <table><tr><td width="700">
                        <![endif]-->



                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
```

[Original design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN5D4.png)
[Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQJBv.png)

I am writing code for a HTML email. I have set `width` and `max-width`s for each `table` however the `table` is not sticking to the specified `width`.

This is causing particular problems in Outlook. I have taken `px` values out (saw a previous post which suggested this) as well as being overly specific with `margin`s!

Does anyone have any advise?

See my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=600" />
            <title>Talent Academy Newsletter</title>
        </head>
    </html>

    <body leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 100% !important; background-color: #FFF; margin:0!important;">
        <table max-width="700" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0"> <!-- // wrapping table // --> 
            <tr>
                <td width="700" align="center" valign="top"> 
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><!-- // not displaying properly & welcome banner table // -->  
                        <tr> 
                            <td align="center" valign="middle" width="700" style="background-color: #e7e7e7; height: 25; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica; color: #000;">
                                <p>Is Outlook ruining this pretty email? Click <strong>here</strong></p>  <!--**add link here when on FTP**--> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td align="center" valign="top" width="700" style="display: block; padding: 0;"> <!-- // welcome banner here // --> 
                                <img src="images/welcome.png" alt="Welcome!" height="340" width="700"> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="470" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0"> <!-- // into copy here // --> <!--be wary of width size here: 470--> 
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" width="470" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: League Gothic, Arial; color: #000; padding-top: 15px;">
                                <p>1st edition <br> September 2016</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" width="470" style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000; padding: 0px, 115px, 0px, 115px;"> <!--used another td as dif font/size --> 
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pharetra justo sed turpis rutrum, non molestie velit vehicula. Suspendisse sed est nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec sem odio, viverra eu velit vitae, posuere blandit orci. Integer placerat tempus tortor in pretium. Donec vitae magna et tortor maximus pulvinar vitae et magna. Nam aliquam molestie commodo.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0">
                        <tr max-width="700">
                            <td max-width="700" align="center" valign="top" width="700" style="display: block; padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom:50px;">
                                <img src="images/fever.png" alt="Welcome!" height="79" width="79">
                                <img src="images/nb.png" alt="Welcome!" height="79" width="79">
                                <img src="images/nbg.png" alt="Welcome!" height="79" width="79">
                                <img src="images/mw.png" alt="Welcome!" height="79" width="79">
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="700" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px 30px 0px;">
                                <img src="images/internal.png" alt="Internal Training" height="85" width="700">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr max-width="700"> 
                            <td width="260" style="display: inline-block; padding: 40px 63.5px 30px 20px;"> <!-- // bottom two //--> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>NAME:</strong> Training course 1 <br><strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi. <br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p>  
                                <img src="images/mw2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                                <img src="images/fever2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                            </td>
                            </td>
                            <td width="3" style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                                <img src="images/line1.png" alt="" height="200" width="3"> 
                            </td>
                            <td width="260" style="display: inline-block; padding: 40px 20px 30px 63.5px;"> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>NAME:</strong> Training course 1 <br><strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi. <br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p> 
                                <img src="images/mw2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                                <img src="images/nbg2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr max-width="700"> 
                            <td width="260" style="display: inline-block; padding: 40px 63.5px 30px 20px;"> <!-- // bottom two //--> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>NAME:</strong> Training course 1 <br><strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi. <br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p>  
                                <img src="images/mw2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                                <img src="images/fever2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                            </td>
                            </td>
                            <td width="3" style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                                <img src="images/line1.png" alt="" height="200" width="3"> 
                            </td>
                            <td width="260" style="display: inline-block; padding: 40px 20px 30px 63.5px;"> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>NAME:</strong> Training course 1 <br><strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi. <br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p> 
                                <img src="images/mw2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                                <img src="images/nbg2.png" alt="NB" height="35" width="32" align="right">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0"> <!-- // start of external training section // --> 
                        <tr max-width="700">
                            <td width="700" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px 30px 0px;">
                                <img src="images/external.png" alt="Internal Training" height="85" width="700"> <!-- // banner image // --> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr max-width="700"> 
                            <td width="260" style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px 63.5px 30px 20px;"> <!-- // bottom two //--> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>NAME:</strong> Training course 1 <br><strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi. <br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p> 
                            </td>
                            <td width="3" style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                                <img src="images/line1.png" alt="" height="150" width="3"> 
                            </td>
                            <td width="260" style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px 20px 30px 63.5px;"> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>NAME:</strong> Training course 1 <br><strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> Nunc ac enim vel nulla euismod placerat a sit amet ligula. Nullam eu ante tempus, efficitur dui eu, pulvinar nisi. <br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p>  
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="700" valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px 30px 0px;">
                                <img src="images/dare.png" alt="Internal Training" height="85" width="700"> <!-- // banner image // --> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td width="380" style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px 0px 30px 20px;"> 
                                <p align="left" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #000;"><strong>PELLENTESQUE HABITANT TRISTIQUE</strong><br>Nam at auctor ante. Integer finibus nisl at euismod iaculis. Proin eleifend nunc ante, hendrerit semper felis pellentesque non. Etiam id quam metus. Ut pretium congue turpis ullamcorper tempus. Vivamus finibus elit ipsum, sit amet egestas dolor condimentum nec.<br><strong>DATE:</strong> 01.01.2017 <br><strong>LOCATION:</strong> Neverland</p> 
                                <img src="images/icon_mail.png" alt="" height="26" width="33">
                                <img src="images/icon_web.png" alt="" height="31" width="31">
                            </td>
                            <td max-width="300" style="display: inline-block; padding: 0px 0px 0px 60px">
                                <img src="images/circle_right.png" alt="Dare to Share" height="255" width="240">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- artwork the circle to reflect the one above --> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>



                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: `max-width` property doesn't work in Outlook, so change it ti `width`

Comment: I have to tell you some sad news, Outlook for most email styles/css will be ignored or modified

Comment: Thanks guys! I've changed my max-widths. 

Reading up on CSS now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-width` is a CSS property, so you can't use it as HTML attribute, and it won't work in Outlook 2007-2013, so use `width` instead.

See more info [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

[image: SS]

Comment: @RachaelNichols what happened to untick the answer as accepted? something not working?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately not! I took out the max-widths but I'm still seeing a shift in col width in Outlook

Comment: - I have uploaded images in the post so you can see :)

Comment: I've done it :) thank you for your help it along with other things I think it made a difference! Fresh eyes definitely helped I think ha.

Comment: Just got here. Wanna show/tell what you did different?

Comment: So, the Outlook I'm using (version 15.23) didn't seem to like any max-width CSS - took those out. As well as display: inline-block. 
I added more <table>'s rather than multiple <td>'s 
Added more styling to the <table> tags so they looked more like this:

<table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top" height="auto" style="left-margin:0; right-margin:0; top-margin:0; margin-height:0;">

And that seemed to do the trick. I also tidied up a bit I was missing a few closing tags! Opps!

Answer (score 1):

`max-width` is not an attribute you set on an element, it's a CSS property you set within the `style` attribute (or in a CSS class if you aren't making emails).

Try changing `<table max-width="700"...` to `<table width="100%" style="max-width:700px;"...`.

You will also want to set a standard `width` as well, since not all email clients will respect your `max-width`.

About `max-width`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

EDIT:

You can use conditionals to target layout in Outlook: https://gist.github.com/elidickinson/5525752

```
<!--[if mso]>
 <center>
 <table><tr><td width="580">
<![endif]-->
 <div style="max-width:580px; margin:0 auto;">

 <p>This text will be centered and constrained to 580 pixels even on Outlook which does not support max-width CSS</p>

 </div>
<!--[if mso]>
 </td></tr></table>
 </center>
<![endif]-->
```

I tested the above code in Outlook 2007 and it worked. This code came from the above github link.

Comment: Thank you, such a helpful answer :)
Looking into these now - will let you know how I get on!

Comment: @RachaelNichols Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a top of depreciate styles in the above tamplate.
`leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0"` Should be replaced with CSS styles.

Also you should read up on CSS support and what can be used in different email clients: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/